# Change behavior of WebGl Screen-Space Projected Lines shader during zoom

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I'm building 2D Graph structure based on Three.js and stack with an issue related to Screen-Space Projected Lines behavior during camera zoom. The issue is lines becomes significantly smaller when I zoom in and much bigger when zoom out.

Examples:

Normal line with predefined thickness:

[image: Normal line with defined thickness]

Line after zooming out:

[image: Line after zooming out]

Line after zooming in:

[image: Line after zooming in]

All other elements which I also build in shaders (circles, rectangles for arrows) have "normal" behavior and change their sizes based on camera position linearly and in opposite direction (becomes bigger on zoom in and smaller on zoom out). I need to reach exactly same behavior with lines in shader but don't know how to do it since quite new in this area.

My lines vertex shader is a slightly adapted version of WestLangley's LineMaterial shader, you can see code below. One observation that I notice:

If I remove dir = normalize (dir) line, lines zoom behavior becomes normal but their thickness starts to be dependent on distance between nodes which is also inappropriate.

Here is VertexShader:

```
      `precision highp float;

        #include <common>
            #include <color_pars_vertex>
            #include <fog_pars_vertex>
            #include <logdepthbuf_pars_vertex>
            #include <clipping_planes_pars_vertex>

       uniform float linewidth;
           uniform vec2 resolution;
           attribute vec3 instanceStart;
           attribute vec3 instanceEnd;
           attribute vec3 instanceColorStart;
           attribute vec3 instanceColorEnd;
           attribute float alphaStart;
           attribute float alphaEnd;
           attribute float widthStart;
           attribute float widthEnd;
           varying vec2 vUv;
           varying float alphaTest;

       void trimSegment( const in vec4 start, inout vec4 end ) {

                 // trim end segment so it terminates between the camera plane and the near plane
                 // conservative estimate of the near plane
                 float a = projectionMatrix[ 2 ][ 2 ]; // 3nd entry in 3th column
                 float b = projectionMatrix[ 3 ][ 2 ]; // 3nd entry in 4th column
                 float nearEstimate = - 0.5 * b / a;
                 float alpha = ( nearEstimate - start.z ) / ( end.z - start.z );

                 end.xyz = mix( start.xyz, end.xyz, alpha );
           }

       void main() {                
            #ifdef USE_COLOR
                        vColor.xyz = ( position.y < 0.5 ) ? instanceColorStart : instanceColorEnd;
                        alphaTest = ( position.y < 0.5 ) ? alphaStart : alphaEnd;
                  #endif

                  float aspect = resolution.x / resolution.y;
                  vUv = uv;

                  // camera space
                  vec4 start = modelViewMatrix * vec4( instanceStart, 1.0 );
                  vec4 end = modelViewMatrix * vec4( instanceEnd, 1.0 );

                  // special case for perspective projection, and segments that terminate either in, or behind, the camera plane
                  // clearly the gpu firmware has a way of addressing this issue when projecting into ndc space
                  // but we need to perform ndc-space calculations in the shader, so we must address this issue directly
                  // perhaps there is a more elegant solution -- WestLangley

                  bool perspective = ( projectionMatrix[ 2 ][ 3 ] == - 1.0 ); // 4th entry in the 3rd column

                  if (perspective) {
                        if (start.z < 0.0 && end.z >= 0.0) {
                              trimSegment( start, end );
                        } else if (end.z < 0.0 && start.z >= 0.0) {
                              trimSegment( end, start );
                        }
                  }

                  // clip space
                  vec4 clipStart = projectionMatrix * start;
                  vec4 clipEnd = projectionMatrix * end;

                  // ndc space
                  vec2 ndcStart = clipStart.xy / clipStart.w;
                  vec2 ndcEnd = clipEnd.xy / clipEnd.w;

                  // direction
                  vec2 dir = ndcEnd - ndcStart;

                  // account for clip-space aspect ratio
                  dir.x *= aspect;
                  dir = normalize( dir );

                  // perpendicular to dir
                  vec2 offset = vec2( dir.y, - dir.x );

                  // undo aspect ratio adjustment
                  dir.x /= aspect;
                  offset.x /= aspect;

                  // sign flip
                  if ( position.x < 0.0 ) offset *= - 1.0;

                  // endcaps, to round line corners
                  if ( position.y < 0.0 ) {
                       // offset += - dir;
                  } else if ( position.y > 1.0 ) {
                       // offset += dir;
                  }

                  // adjust for linewidth
                  offset *= (linewidth * widthStart);

                  // adjust for clip-space to screen-space conversion // maybe resolution should be based on viewport ...
                  offset /= resolution.y;

                  // select end
                  vec4 clip = ( position.y < 0.5 ) ? clipStart : clipEnd;

                  // back to clip space
                  offset *= clip.w;

                  clip.xy += offset;

                  gl_Position = clip;

                  vec4 mvPosition = ( position.y < 0.5 ) ? start : end; // this is an approximation

                  #include <logdepthbuf_vertex>
                  #include <clipping_planes_vertex>
                  #include <fog_vertex>
       }`
```

FragmentShader:

```
`precision highp float;

       #include <common>
           #include <color_pars_fragment>
           #include <fog_pars_fragment>
           #include <logdepthbuf_pars_fragment>
           #include <clipping_planes_pars_fragment>

       uniform vec3 diffuse;
           uniform float opacity;
           varying vec2 vUv;
           varying float alphaTest;

       void main() {                   
         if ( abs( vUv.y ) > 1.0 ) {
                     float a = vUv.x;
                     float b = ( vUv.y > 0.0 ) ? vUv.y - 1.0 : vUv.y + 1.0;
                     float len2 = a * a + b * b;

                     if ( len2 > 1.0 ) discard;
               }

               vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, alphaTest );

               #include <logdepthbuf_fragment>
               #include <color_fragment>

               gl_FragColor = vec4( diffuseColor.rgb, diffuseColor.a );

               #include <premultiplied_alpha_fragment>
               #include <tonemapping_fragment>
               #include <encodings_fragment>
               #include <fog_fragment>

       }`
```

Will really appreciate any help on how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested idea, based on your comments about the effects of the `normalize()` call.  Swap the order of these lines:

```
dir = normalize( dir );
vec2 offset = vec2( dir.y, - dir.x );
```

becomes

```
vec2 offset = vec2( dir.y, - dir.x );
dir = normalize( dir );
```

so that `offset` still depends on the original length of `dir` (which I hope should make the visible line width behave correctly), and you still have the normalization (which I hope should make the visible line length behave correctly).

Comment: Nevermind, I misinterpreted your comments about thickness depending on node separation - this answer is probably wrong.  Perhaps the simplest solution is to scale your linewidth uniform by the zoom factor.

Comment: Perfect, thank's Claude, this is works exactly as I expect. For everyone who is interested in solution: `line offset *= (linewidth * widthStart)` should be extended by scaleFactor: `offset *= (linewidth * widthStart * scaleFactor);` Where scaleFactor is a zoom coefficient (translate.k in my case since I use D3.js for 2D canvas scaling).